# git migrate from LFS to normal repo

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-lfs

There is LFS git repository hosted at Bitbucket server.
Now we do not need LFS.

How to migrate from git LFS repository back to normal repository?

If repo with LFS - there are "pointers" instead of files in the commits.
And if I need to remove LFS - I should use files instead of "pointers".
So how replace all "pointers" with files in commit history?

Suggest, that it is something like `git lfs smudge` but should be applied for all log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrate from old LFS repo to new LFS repo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366931/migrate-from-old-lfs-repo-to-new-lfs-repo)

Comment: @Andy no. There are different questions

Comment: Did you find a solution for your question. I am also interested in this question...

Answer (score 7):

I came across this issue today when I didn't want to use LFS anymore for a project on github.

**To get information** about the entire repository, you do:

```
git lfs migrate info --everything
```

Then, when you decide what you want to **migrate**, you use:

```
git lfs migrate export --everything --include="*.png, *.unity, *.hdr, *.clip, ArtifactDB"
```

Where *--everything* means all branches and in the *--include* option you list the file types you wish to migrate.

**Important:** This will rewrite all history and potentially you will have to either **overwrite remote** with --force or **copy the new repo** into some other server.