# Migrate from old LFS repo to new LFS repo?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-lfs

There is LFS git repository hosted at Bitbucket server. Now we need to create new LFS repo and move repository there with LFS storage.

How to do this?

---

For example for normal repo we can do:

```
git remote add new NEW_REMOTE_REPO_URL 
git push —-all NEW_REPO_URL
```

Will LFS storage be created with all history for new repo?

Comment: https://github.com/bozaro/git-lfs-migrate

Comment: Though to me it seems it could have been `git-lfs fetch --all` and some `git git-lfs push ...`

Comment: as I know `git-lfs-migrate` is for converting repo that is without LFS to LFS. But for this I used BFG https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/ and seems it is much better. Here is example https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/releases/tag/v1.12.5

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct, I should have read more carefully

Answer (score 17):

> ```
> git remote add new NEW_REMOTE_REPO_URL 
> git push —-all NEW_REPO_URL
> ```

Basically yes this will do what you want, but it would fail if you don't have all lfs data cached locally. To get it you should run before your commands:

```
git lfs fetch --all
```

PS: you could also run `git lfs push --all new` to only push lfs data, but `git push` will push them also, if the `pre-push` hook is set up

Comment: if git lfs is turn on in new repo, you need change lfs.url to new repo, or git push newrepo will be failed. change lfs.url by following command: git config lfs.url <new_repo_url>

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the lfs endpoint in your local repo by doing something like:
`git config lfs.url = "https://my_other_server.example.com/foo/bar/info/lfs"`

If you need it to stick in the repository, they recommend:

`git config -f .lfsconfig lfs.url https://my_other_server.example.com/foo/bar/info/lfs
git add .lfsconfig`

See https://github.com/github/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial#lfs-url

Comment: yes. But this is just change LFS server url. How to migrate existing LFS storage to new LFS storage that is attached to new repo?